# in Google Collaboratory, what is the code for telling the AI/ML to show/print on the screen the model that it predicted?

Tags: google-colaboratory

see the code below for a basic ML test. I ran this, but wanted to see the mathematical formula predicted by the AI using the given xs and ys array set, and the training x value.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow import keras

model = tf.keras.Sequential([keras.layers.Dense(units=1, input_shape=[1])])

model.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss = 'mean_squared_error')

xs = np.array([-3.0, -2.0, -1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0], dtype=float)
ys = np.array([-3.0, -2.0, -1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0], dtype=float)

model.fit(xs,ys,epochs=10)

print(model.predict([-2.5]))
```